# Add character after another character Postgresql

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, padding

I have a table with the faithful "code"

```
Code character varying (10) NOT NULL,
....
```

The data must be like `VXXXXXXXXX` | `JXXXXXXXXX` where x are numbers with 9 digits, is there a way to add "0" in the numbers with 8 digits or less?

if I get: `VXXX` add `0` to get `V000000XXX`?

I want to do this using triggers.

Comment: Is the prefix always exactly a single character?

Comment: Yes is always is a single character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the prefix is always exactly one character, you can do something like this:

```
concat(left(code,1), lpad(substr(code,2), 8, '0'))
```

Comment: Working perfectly!  Thanks a lot